# Sharepoint 2013 Standard - Changes not saved even after check in

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

A user has a problem with her Excel file where changes are not saved (or seem to be anyway) even though she has "checked it in" ...

"... OK, I now see the checkout option.

So I checked it out, then I had to select edit,

I made a change and saved and closed. It didn’t ask if I wanted to check it in.

I selected check in and entered the comment “test”

It’s now showing checked it BUT the change I made is not captured. That is, it didn’t process my update!"

Any ideas... I think it is only for this user which is also a member of our "Sharepoint Contributors" AD group. No one else has this problem.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Does the library have content approval selected?  It might be that the document needs to published before the changes show.

Comment: thanks BrenClarke ... I will check .. just getting the hang of this SP 2013 app and I must say it is impressive... much better than what it was way back when... after I understand it I want to integrate it with Yammer (I am a fan of Yammer)

Comment: thanks BrenClarke ... I don't know where to check for this setting under Library -> Library Settings ...don't know why one person can but the other cannot  ..